# Error "getsockname failed: Not a socket" on Windows 10

Tags: ssh, php-deployer

I am successfully connecting to the server via cmd , but I get error after send command of deploy

`error getsockname failed: Not a socket`

Running command in cmd from project directory
`call vendor/bin/dep deploy st1`

Deployer version: 6.8.0
PHP version: 7.3
my OS: Windows 10 x64

```
✈︎ Deploying master on st1.XXXX.ru

➤ Executing task deploy:prepare

✔ Executing task deploy:failed

➤ Executing task deploy:unlock

In Client.php line 103:

  The command "rm -f /home/admin/web/st1.XXXX.ru/.dep/deploy.lock" failed.  

  Exit Code: -1 (Unknown error)

  Host Name: st1.XXXX.ru

  ================
  getsockname failed: Not a socket
  packet_write_poll: Connection to UNKNOWN port -1: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Three solutions:

- Disable `set ('ssh_multiplexing', false);` in the file deployer.php
  or
- in options use the `dep deploy -o ssh_multiplexing=false`
  or
- deploy through your git bash

And be sure to disable `set('git_tty', false);` (It's not support in Windows)

**
*Use option `-vvv` with deploy command to see more information about deploying.*

Comment: It is a very bad decision to use example # 1. If you are developing on Windows, then your deployer will not work for those developers who are working in parallel on the same project for Unix